# Reactjs - create factory, passing props into component

Tags: reactjs

Trying to achieve the following:

```
if(typeof window === 'undefined'){
    return React.renderToString(React.createFactory(AppComponent)());
}
React.render(<AppComponent component={component} />, document.body);
```

How exactly can I pass in the `component` prop to the component when it's being put through the `createFactory` method?

EDIT:

Got it working:

```
renderApp: function(component){
    if(typeof window === 'undefined'){
        var appComponentFactory = React.createFactory(AppComponent);
        return React.renderToString(appComponentFactory({
            component: component
        }));
    }
    React.render(<AppComponent component={component} />, document.body);
}
```

Comment: how can you create a factory component using itself ?

Comment: Iv'e removed answer as the more i look at your question the more confused i am. Could you sum up whats wrong a little more ? how do you expect you can define something as itself ?

Comment: maybe something like this ? http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/10/14/introducing-react-elements.html#react-without-jsx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're already transpiling JSX for the `React.render()` call, you don't need to jump through hoops with factories...

```
renderApp: function(component){
    var app = <AppComponent component={component}/>
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
      return React.renderToString(app);
    }
    React.render(app, document.body);
}
```

...since it's just sugar for:

```
var app = React.createElement(AppComponent, {component: component})
```

---

This may not apply, but If your `AppComponent` isn't doing anything but rendering the `component` prop it's given, you could also just render the component directly:

```
renderApp: function(Component) {
    var app = <Component/>
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
      return React.renderToString(app);
    }
    React.render(app, document.body);
}
```

...showing the desugaring again:

```
var app = React.createElement(Component)
```